# Azure Active Directory: ACS50000: There was an error issuing a token

Tags: authentication, azure, model-view-controller, active-directory, azure-web-roles

I'm using Azure Active Directory (AD) to access ASP.NET MVC application. At the same time it works for some countries when doesn't work, for example, for US IP addresses, despite Region for AD has been set to United States. The error message below:

Sign in
Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.

Something went wrong.

Additional technical information:
Trace ID: a357d9ac-4253-485a-9d07-1f7f8e0d4ceb
Timestamp: 2014-03-26 08:34:39Z
ACS50000: There was an error issuing a token.

Did anyone has this issue or have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 days the problem was resolved automatically. Looks like it needs five days to sync AD to all countries. Before that it worked only for country, which application was created from in Azure Management Portal.